# Payload class type changes when exiting from sub-flow

Tags: mule

I am playing around with [example](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Service+Orchestration+and+Choice+Routing+Example) on the mulesoft portal, I see some weird behavior when using sub-flows in this example.

The Payload class type changes when exiting from sub-flow.

The interesting section is below

[image: Subflow]

```
 <sub-flow name="Samsung_SubFlow">
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="OrderIrem_To_OrderRequest" doc:name="OrderItem To OrderRequest"/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="samsung/orders" method="POST" port="9090" doc:name="samsung/orders"/> -->
        <flow-ref name="samsungWebServiceClient" doc:name="samsungWebServiceClient"/>
        <logger message="After just returning into the main flow #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Main flow"/>
        <message-property-filter pattern="http.status=200" caseSensitive="true" scope="inbound" doc:name="Filter failures"/>
        <set-session-variable variableName="totalCost" value="#[totalCost+payload.price]" doc:name="totalCost=+price"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="OrderResponse_to_PurchaseReceipt" doc:name="OrderResponse to PurchaseReceipt"/>
    </sub-flow>
    <sub-flow name="samsungWebServiceClient">
      <cxf:jaxws-client clientClass="com.mulesoft.se.samsung.SamsungServiceService" doc:name="Samsung Webservice Client" operation="purchase" port="SamsungServicePort"/>
      <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" doc:name="/samsung/orders" method="POST" path="samsung/orders" port="9090"/>
        <logger message="At the end of the subflow #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Sub-flow exit"/>
   </sub-flow>
```

The two loggers give out the below

> INFO  2015-05-10 17:32:07,016
>   [[service-orchestration].Orders_HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01]
>   org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: At the end of the
>   subflow org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@1ba9d893 INFO 
>   2015-05-10 17:32:15,219
>
> [[service-orchestration].Orders_HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01]
>   org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: After just returning
>   into the main flow com.mulesoft.se.samsung.OrderResponse@70d5a09f

**Note how the payload type has changed from BufferInputStream to OrderResponse !!**

I do not think that this is expected behavior, as obviously if I embed the MP's from the sub-flow into the main-flow the flow fails as the payload class type is not OrderResponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the CXF processor is an intercepting message processor, so it performs some actions right after the processor chain is executed (in this case the second sub flow). In order to alter this behavior, you can surround the cxf client with `<processor-chain>` tags.

Comment: You hit the nail on its head !! , can you point me towards some documentation around "intercepting message processor" please. and which other processors work like this ? -- basically any links around this area will be much appreciated.

Comment: There isn't much to it documented, you can probably see this http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Custom+Message+Processors for a little further explanation, but in this case is just familiarity with mule's source code.

Comment: I did read through this, also tried to dig through the code but could not find the bit where the stream is converted into orderresponse , could you point me to the relevant code block please